# Play from base64 string in react-native-audio-recorder-player

Tags: react-native, audio, audio-player

I need to play audio from base64 encoded string in react-native using react-native-audio-recorder-player by either converting to file or directly playable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used below code to write new file with RNFS (react-native-fs) and react-native-audio-recorder-player to play the song from path uri.

```
const path = `${RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath}/${i}.aac`;
RNFS.writeFile(path, question.file, 'base64').then(() => startPlayer(path))
```